# Unable to access or analyze external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, fsck

a friend gave me a corrupted HDD. He said, his laptop crashed during a formatting process with a BSOD. Now from time to time (on Windows) it's being detected but if you try to access it, it prints errors and is not found any longer.

I tried it with various applications but wasn't even able to analyze it.

It wasn't even found by GParted. fsck, smartctl and ntfsfix all failed.

There's no data on it so nothing is needed to be recovered but the drive is just half an year old and so it's annoying to throw it away.

Any suggestions what else I can do?

Thanks in Advance

Greetz

0x30

Here the outputs of the linux commands:

smartctl

```
    sudo smartctl -d scsi -T /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [x86_64-linux-4.1.2-2-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=======> INVALID ARGUMENT TO -T: /dev/sdb
=======> VALID ARGUMENTS ARE: normal, conservative, permissive, verypermissive <=======

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

ntfsfix

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

fsck (sorry for german, just says bad magic number, unreadable superblock)

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sdb
fsck von util-linux 2.26.2
fsck.ext2: Ungültige magische Zahl im Superblock beim Versuch, /dev/sdb zu öffnen
/dev/sdb: 
Der Superblock ist unlesbar bzw. beschreibt kein gültiges ext2/ext3/ext4-
Dateisystem. Wenn das Gerät gültig ist und ein ext2/ext3/ext4-
Dateisystem (kein swap oder ufs usw.) enthält, dann ist der Superblock
beschädigt, und Sie könnten versuchen, e2fsck mit einem anderen Superblock
zu starten:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <Gerät>
 oder
    e2fsck -b 32768 <Gerät>
```

Comment: I got the impression that the drive (not the data on the drive, but the drive itself) might be broken. Can you add the SMART data of the drive to your post. (e.g. use `smartctl` with a valid syntax).

Comment: Smartctl open device: /dev/sdb failed: INQUIRY failed

Answer (score 1):

> a friend gave me a corrupted HDD. He said, his laptop crashed during
>   a formatting process with a BSOD.
>
> Now from time to time (on Windows) it's being detected but if you try 
>   to access it, it prints errors and is not found any longer.

First step here is to analyse:

- Is windows having a problem with the drive,
- Or is the drive misbehaving,
- Or is it something in between (e.g. a bad cable).

Now assuming that you are not trying to use your friends laptop, or any of his cables that leaves us with the first two options.

The first step now is to check that the drive is properly connected (SATA cable plugged in, connector solid and not loose. Power cable plugged in etc etc). Next boot your computer and go to its firmware (BIOS, UEFI, ...).

If the firmware does not detect the drive at this stage then you can ignore any programs. The problem is at a much lower level.  To be blunt, the drive is probably [mostly] broken. Since just half an year old you can return it under warranty.

If it is detected in the firmware then the drive might be fine. In that case a dispart clean (windows) or similar command from gpart should work.

If the drive does show now and then and keeps dropping then do check the connections again. Make sure there is no loose (half broken-off) connector.  Try a different data cable. If all those fail send it back to the manufacturer.

You should be able to do this even if you do not have the sales receipt. The serial number on the drive will indicate roughly how old it is and drive warranties are often 1 or 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive was suddenly left without power during format there are two options – it could have suffered mechanical damage, in this case you should get it replaced or there is no mechanical damage but the formatting is messed up and the OS cannot read and mount it.

First you need to check the possibility of hardware failure so look for the HDD manufacturer diagnostics tool and scan the HDD health. It would better if the diagnostics is available for DOS since is very likely this HDD will cause Windows to stuck.

If the HDD is showing good health perform a full write zeros/secure erase and you should be able to use it.

If it fails the test check if you can get a warranty replacement.